# Django : NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

everyone!
I'm new to Django and actually making a study project. I'm getting a NoReverseMatch exception and can't understand why. It seems not to have namespace conflicts, the other list views are made in the same way as for the StoredItem model, but only this one throws an exception:
 
models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class LegalEntity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Name")
    rif = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text="RIF")
    address = models.TextField(help_text="Address")
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=15, help_text="Phone number")

    def __str__(self):
        pass


class Contract(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Name")
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Contract number")
    description = models.TextField(help_text="Contract description")
    start_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, help_text="Start date")
    expiry_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text="Expiry date")

    def __str__(self):
        return "number: {0}, " \
               "name: \"{1}\", " \
               "starts: {2}, " \
               "expires: {3}."\
              .format(self.number, self.name, self.start_date, self.expiry_date)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('contract-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Provider(LegalEntity):
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract)

    def __str__(self):
        return "name: \"{0}\", " \
               "RIF: {1}, " \
               "phone: {2}."\
               .format(self.name, self.rif, self.phone_num)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('provider-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Name")
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Serial No.")
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Manufacturer")
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)

    def __str__(self):
        return "name: \"{0}\", " \
               "serial: {1}, " \
               "manufacturer: {2}," \
               "provider: {3}."\
              .format(self.name, self.serial, self.manufacturer, self.provider.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('item-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class StoredItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} - {1}, {2} pcs.".format(self.item.serial, self.item.name, self.quantity)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('storeditem-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'almacen'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^providers/$', views.ProviderListView.as_view(), name='providers'),
    url(r'^items/$', views.ItemListView.as_view(), name='items'),
    url(r'^storeditems/$', views.StoredItemListView.as_view(), name='storeditems'),
    url(r'^contracts/$', views.ContractListView.as_view(), name='contracts')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic

# Create your views here.
from almacen.models import Contract, StoredItem, Provider, Item


def index(request):
    stored_items_num = len([x for x in StoredItem.objects.all() if x.quantity > 0])
    providers_num = Provider.objects.all().count()

    return render(request, 
    'index.html',
    context = {'stored_items_num': stored_items_num, 'providers_num': providers_num})


class ContractListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Contract


class ProviderListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Provider


class ItemListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Item


class StoredItemListView(generic.ListView):
    model = StoredItem
```

base_template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        {% block title %}<title>Almacen Application</title>{% endblock %}
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Добавление дополнительного статического CSS файла -->
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
                        <h4>Options: </h4>
                        {% block sidebar %}
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <li><a href="{% url 'almacen:index' %}">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url 'almacen:items' %}">Items</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url 'almacen:providers' %}">Providers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url 'almacen:contracts' %}">Contracts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url 'almacen:storeditems' %}">Store</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 ">
                        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer id="center" class="container-fluid">
            <p>
                PerfoSAP Package Application<br>
                created by caesar_84
            </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

storeditem_list.html

```
{% extends 'base_template.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Items list</h1>

    {% if storeditem_list %}

        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Serial</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Manufacturer</th>
                <th>Provider</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>

            {% for storeditem in storeditem_list %}

            <tr>
                <td>
                <a href="{{storeditem.get_absolute_url}}"> {{ storeditem.item.serial }} </a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ storeditem.item.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ storeditem.item.manufacturer }}</td>
                <td>{{ storeditem.item.provider.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ storeditem.quantity }}</td>
            </tr>

            {% endfor %}
        </table>

    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

This is the message I'm getting:

> Reverse for 'storeditem-detail' not found. 'storeditem-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: I dont see any detail view in the code.

Comment: It still doesn't have any, I want to implement the list views first.

Comment: where do you get 'contract-detail' from ? I dont see it in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error that stole me some hours today xD
The error is in storeditem_list.html in the line

```
<a href="{{storeditem.get_absolute_url}}"> {{ storeditem.item.serial }} </a>
```

Instead of `"{{storeditem.get_absolute_url}}"` it had to be `"{{storeditems.get_absolute_url}}"`